# How to create a new hypothesis from apply?

Tags: coq

When I run the Coq script below (a simplification of the original one):

```
Inductive w (g: nat): nat -> Prop:=
 | z: w g 0.

Lemma x:
  forall (i j: nat), w i j -> (forall k: nat, k <= k).
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma y:
  forall (m n: nat),
  w m n -> w m n.
Proof.
  intros m n H. 
  apply x in H.
```

I get the following error message on the last line:

> Error: Unable to find an instance for the variable k.

Can anybody explain to me why this happens and what I have to do in order to have `forall k: nat, k <= k` as a new hypothesis in the context?

Thanks in advance,
Marcus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `apply x in H`, you can use `pose proof (x _ _ H)`. This will give you the hypothesis you're looking for.

From the Coq tactic manual,

> `apply term in ident` tries to match the conclusion
>   of the type of `ident` against a non-dependent
>   premise of the type of `term`, trying them from right to left.

I think the key point to note here is that `apply` only works for non-dependent premises, while the premise you want it to match, `i=j`, is dependent. However, the particular error message returned by Coq is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Since your lemma `x` contains an inner universal quantification (the `forall k` part at the end),
Coq does not manage to guess which natural number you want to use. By applying `x`to `H`, you only provide `i` and `j`. You have two solutions:

1. provide the relevant `k` by hand using the `apply x with (k := foo) in H` syntax
2. ask Coq to introduce a "meta-variable" (think of it as a typed hole that you will fill later) using the `eapply` [`tactic`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.eapply)

Hope it helps,
V.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I still don´t understand why Coq simply does not return  (forall k: nat, k <= k) as the new hypothesis, once I have supplied H. I would appreciate if you could clarify that for me. Best Regards.

Comment: I honestly don't know. You should ask the devs on the Coq-club mailing list.